# Fubini's theorem on a flow

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Suppose $f \in L^1(X)$ and let $\phi_s :X \to X$ be a one parameter measure preserving flow that is also measurable on $\mathbb{R} \times X$.  Show that for almost every $x \in X$ the function $f(\phi_s(x))$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

This seems like a straightforward application of Fubini's theorem but I'm not sure how to apply it.  The intuition is that if $f$ is integrable on all of $X$ then it should also be integrable on the entire orbit of x along the flow for a.e. $x \in X$.  The only issue is that the orbit of $x$ might create a path of measure zero in $X$ that $f$ blows up on.  How do we know that this happens infrequently enough?

Comment: What is a "measure preserving flow"? Does it just mean that $\phi_s$ is measure preserving for each $s \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: It seems false. Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability space. Take $\phi_s(x) = x$ for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$, and take $f = 1$.

Comment: nevermind, I changed it to be locally integrable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick consequence of the fact that $\phi_s$ is measure-preserving. In particular, for any integrable function $f$, we have $$\int f\circ\phi_s\,d\mu = \int f\,d\mu.\tag{1}$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^1\int |f|\circ \phi_s\,d\mu\,ds = \int_0^1\int |f|\,d\mu\,ds = \int |f|\,d\mu < \infty.
$$
The claim follows by Fubini's theorem.

To prove $(1)$, observe $(1)$ holds for indicator functions of measurable sets $E\subset X$ by definition, then simple functions by linearity, non-negative functions by monotone convergence, and then integrable functions by decomposing $f = f^+-f^-$.

Comment: +1. A simple proof of (1) can for example be found in these lecture notes: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/ergodic-theory/lecture11.pdf

Comment: We need to show that $\int_0^1 f (\phi_s(x)) ds$ exists though, without the $d \mu$.

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange: By Tonelli's theorem, what $\int_0^1\int |f|\circ \phi_s\,d\mu\,ds = \int_0^1\int |f|\,d\mu\,ds = \int |f|\,d\mu < \infty$ shows is that $\int_0^1 f\circ \phi_s\,ds$ exists and is finite $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: Thanks.  If I had changed the problem to $[0,t]$ then I can use the same argument to say that for every $t$ the integral $\int_0^t f(\phi_s)ds$ exists a.e. right?  (instead of almost every t)

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange: That's correct. More generally, $\int_F f(\phi_s(x))\,ds$ exists and is finite $\mu$-a.e. as long as $\int_F1\,ds < \infty$.